# Physical memory runs out after sql changes

Tags: windows-server-2008, memory, performance-monitoring, memory-usage

We have an 2008 r2 server working for 5 years, its physical memory was always around 70% but after our last site code and SQL stored procedures and functions updates it got to 94-96% and all the pages of the site became slow, most of users get timeout errors.

The server is 64 bit, has 8gb ram and the SQL db is around 15gb and we have around 50 users.

My top priority is to let users to run pages fast and stop this SQL timeouts not by getting the timeout waiting time bigger, because this will make users wait almost 2 min until the data will be loaded to page.

I am not an expert in servers but I did run some settings checks to show you for help.

Please see the provided screenshot and share how the issue can be handled. These are the SQL settings I have:
[image: SQL Settings]

This is the SQL query I run to see locks:

[image: SQL Lock]

Comment: 8Gb of memory isn't enough, and it's super cheap right now, add some

Comment: Then start working on your plans to EOL it; a sysadmin's work is never done.

Comment: Max Server Memory = 2147483647 MB. That is about 2TB of RAM. It sounds like your server is swapping memory pretty hard. I recommend a reboot first, then a RAM upgrade (if the mobo supports it), then EOL for the server, if EOL is not an option then consult with an MSSQL expert for 2-5 hours.

Comment: unfortunately i cannot upgrade ram on that server, its not an option i can do. what is EOL?  do you mean end of life ? why? i cannot just kill this site is lifesaver.

Comment: it was all working fine before, can you just point me what type of code changes could cause the increase in the physical memory load? i cannot find any open connections